# Problem with opening parquet files with fastparquet after updating to latest version

Tags: dask, fastparquet

I had a bunch of parquet files created like this:

```
dd.to_parquet(df, 'dir/of/parquet', partition_on=['month', 'day'], engine='fastparquet')
```

I used to read a subset of the columns like this:

```
raw_data_view = dd.read_parquet('data/raw_data_fast_par.par', columns=['@timestamp', 'http_user','dst', 'dst_port', 'http_req_method', 'http_req_header_host', 'http_req_header_referer', 'http_req_header_useragent', 'http_req_secondleveldomain'],
                       engine='fastparquet', filters=[('@timestamp', '>=', np.datetime64(start)), ('@timestamp', '<', np.datetime64(end))])
```

before updating to `dask 2.2.0` and latest fastparquet it worked correctly. Now I get this messages. On executing read command:

```
RuntimeWarning: Multiple sorted columns found, cannot autodetect index
RuntimeWarning,
```

and upon calling compute:

```
ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns in the provided metadata
Expected: ['@timestamp', 'http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port', 'http_req_method', 'http_req_header_host', 'http_req_header_referer', 'http_req_header_useragent', 'http_req_secondleveldomain']
Actual:   ['@timestamp', 'http_user', 'dst', 'dst_port', 'http_req_method', 'http_req_header_host', 'http_req_header_referer', 'http_req_header_useragent', 'http_req_secondleveldomain', 'month', 'day']
```

Has something changed?

Comment: Does it work correctly without the `columns=`?

Comment: Recommend you raise an issue with full reproducer, and reference at https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/5218 . Yes, the parquet code was rewritten and simplified, we hope not to have broken workflows...

Comment: Removing the `columns=`  parameter works.